# Magento Error - Invalid block type

Tags: php, magento, server

I have moved magento website from one server http://example_old.com/ to another server http://example.com/beta/. But on category/product listing page does not show, only blank screen is appear. When check on error log it shows following error :

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Page_Block_Header' in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/beta/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('page/header', Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('page/header', 'header')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('page/header', 'header')
```

Same blank screen is appear on admin panel.

What is the cause of this error? On old server it was working properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 6 months later but I have a solution if you still need it.

I was having a similar problem. I installed the patches into my 1.9.2.1 installation and then suddenly my product listing pages were blank.
Like you, I went to the logs and saw that error. But I feel that this error is loosely related to the blank product listing page you are having.

To deal with the this error I went to my layout file, I was referencing the header then loading it as a child block:

```
<reference name="header">
        <block type="page/header" name="header">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                ...
```

When all I needed to do was reference it, so I removed the block:

```
<reference name="header">
        <action method="setTemplate">
```

This resolved the error log, but not by blank product listing page. I am not sure what version of Magento you are running but I have read that people have had issues with Static block shortcodes in version 1.9.2.2 [see here for details](https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Static-block-shortcodes-not-working-1-9-2-2/td-p/20096)

### If you are using static blocks in your categories

I was using static block shortcodes for some categories. To fix this (as pointed of by dudesjoerd from the above article) You have to head to System > Permissions > Blocks: and allow any block type you are using (if any)

### If you are NOT using static blocks in your categories

Since you were migrating from server to server as opposed to applying patches I can only suggest that your PHP versions are different and there are version errors in your product listing phtml file.

I hope this helps you buddy!

Comment: @ Chirs Rogers : When admin edit any cofigurable product then this exception comes. how to fix it have any idea?